# The probability of something being true if we know the probability of something and how trustworthy a comment is

Tags: probability

So here is the question and I'm sure it's not that hard to work out, but for some reason, I really just can't do this, I have NO idea where to start.

A taxi was involved in a hit and run accident at night. Two taxi companies, the Green and the
Blue, operate in the city. $85\%$ of the taxis in the city are Green and $15\%$ are Blue. A witness is
found who has seen the incident. The court tests the reliability of the witness under the same
circumstances that existed on the night of the accident and concludes that the witness correctly
identifies each one of the two colors $80\%$ of the time.

What is the probability that the taxi involved in the accident was Blue given that the witness
identifies it as Blue? How much weight should the court put on this evidence?

I feel like it should be the $P(A|B)$ formula, but don't know how to apply it in this circumstance.

Comment: This is a classic example of [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem). First identify what the events $A$ and $B$ should be, then simply apply the formula (you will need to use the [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Statement) to evaluate $P(B)$)

Comment: I always get 0.8*0.15, my A is that it is blue and my B is that he has said it is. I don't get why this isn't obvious to me

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to try using Law of total probability. Imma try again

Comment: Yes, $0.8\times0.15$ is just the numerator of the fraction in Bayes Theorem

Comment: But my denominator is $P(A)$ and I get back to $0.8$. Sorry if this is sounding stupid, i've been on this question an hour and know I should know this easily.

Comment: See my answer, I have written out the probabilities you need to combine. If you still get a wrong answer, can you edit your question with what multiplications you did, so I can try to see your mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Bayes theorem: $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(\text{he said it is blue given it is blue})P(\text{it is blue})}{P(\text{he said it is blue})}$$

So we get a numerator of $${P(\text{he said it is blue given it is blue})P(\text{it is blue})}$$ and a denominator of $${P(\text{he said it is blue given it is blue})P(\text{it is blue})+P(\text{he said it is blue given it is green})P(\text{it is green})}$$by the law of total probability - $P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|\neg A)P(\neg A)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are asked to figure out the conditional probability $P(A |B)$ with:

$A$: The taxi in the Accident was blue

$B$: the witness identifies the taxi as Blue

I assume you were also taught Bayes' theorem:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B)}$$

You know a few things:

$P(B|A)=0.8$ (if it really was blue, the witness identifies it as blue with a probability of $80$%)

$P(A) =0.15$ (this is the unconditional or *prior* probability that the taxi is blue. That is, not knowing anything about the taxi involved in the accident other than it was a taxi, the prior probability of it being blue is $15$%)

Now, can you figure out how to get $P(B)$? That is, if we take a random taxi from this City, what is the probability this person identifies it as blue?